# Wrting a HTTP proxy in Java using only the Socket class

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to write an HTTP  proxy in Java using only the Socket class.  I had attempted to construct one earlier, and I was successfully sending a request by writing to the socket's output stream  But I am having a hard time reading the response.  the research I have conducted suggests that I should use the input stream and read it line by line, but I have not been able to read any web-pages successfully using this method.  Would anyone have any suggestions as to where I could go from here?

My code actually uses a byte buffer to read from the input stream in order to read the page in bytes:

```
    InputStream input = clientSocket.getInputStream()
    byte[] buffer = new byte[48*1024];
    byte[] redData;
    StringBuilder clientData = new StringBuilder();
    String redDataText;
    int red;
       while((red = input.read(buffer)) > -1) {
           redData = new byte[red];
           System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, redData, 0, red);
           redDataText = new String(redData, "UTF-8");
           System.out.println("Got message!! " + redDataText);
           clientData.append(redDataText);
       }
```

Comment: Too broad. You need to start by reading RFC 2616, especially the parts relating to content length. You also need to write data read directly to the peer socket, not accumulate it in memory first. You're wasting time and space.

Comment: I did a project like this for a course once. Are you using Threads for a multi-threaded proxy server or no? You could use [this](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/java-simple-proxy-socket-server-examples) as reference. Example 2 would be one without threads.

Comment: Where did you conduct that research? Not here. If you had looked here you would just be copying bytes back and forth. You can't assume that HTTP request and response bodies consist of lines, or even characters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are asking for a way to read an InputStream by lines, this one may serve you:

```
    BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
    String line;
    StringBuilder clientData=new StringBuilder();
    while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        clientData.append(line);
    }
```

You have to be careful not to read an InputStream in this fashion unless you are a priori sure that it contains *just plain text* (and not binary data).

BTW: For shake of efficiency, I recommend you to pre-size the clientData with an initial size according to the final size (if not, it will start from a default size of 10, and will need to be re-sized more times).

Comment: This is not a correct way to read an HTTP response, except under certain stringent conditions which you haven't specified.

Comment: @EJP The OP is requesting some method to "use the input stream and read it line by line". And I've also specified that this is only useful for _plain text data_. So I don't agree with your point... unless you were so kind to explain, at least, what are those "stringent conditions".

Comment: No. The OP is trying to write a proxy. The statement about reading line by line is from the so-called 'research' that he had 'conducted', which I have already commented on. It is part of the problem, not part of the solution. You cannot write a proxy using line I/O. The conditions include two that I have already stated in comments, and also that the data is terminated by end of stream. These are all special cases in HTTP.

Comment: @EJP OK. I agree: In a proxy, the data should be written directly to the outputstream peer, and this solution relies upon end-of-stream. But it's not a broad question; the question is quite clear and specific, and I've tried to answer it clear and specifically. If you understand there are other conditions the OP's author should take in account, post your own answer and let him/her decide.